# Using nHibernate with st_geometry

Tags: nhibernate, esri

Has any one know a way to use nHibernate with database tables that coontains ESRI's st_geometry columns?

This corrently prevents us the usage with nHibernate in our applications.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Nhibernate GIS operations use [NTS NetTopologySuite.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nts) It has the interfaces IGeometry , IPoint etc.

You can manipulate spatial datastructures with these libraries

Answer (score 0):

you can use [NHibernate.Spatial](http://www.codeplex.com/NHibernateSpatial) to work with those columns. i successfully used nHibernate.Spatial with SQL Server 2008 and geometry/geography columns.

nHibernate.Spatial uses GeoAPI and NTS NetTopologySuite too as Cherian stated in the previous answer.

Comment: Thanks for the replay

We use Oracle as our database, so we can't use NHibernate.Spatial - it doesn't support Oracle for now.
According to what I read in the docs, NHibernate spatial supports only the native geographic types in SqlServer 2008 and not esri's type...

Comment: you could try to implement a custom type as an IUserType and doing the conversion for yourself